# SQL Server : don't send email if transaction rolls back

Tags: sql-server

I have a piece of code that uses TRY / CATCH to roll back a transaction if an `INSERT` fails. However, in the middle of the code I have a piece of code that sends out an email per loop round.

The problem that I'm having is that the loop sends out the email and then makes an insert. So Let's say that after 9 processes/rounds, the 10th round fails to `INSERT`; then the whole transaction is rolled back, but the 9 emails have already been sent. How can I improve it so that the emails are not sent first? Or how to avoid any emails to be sent if a transaction fails?

Here is a simplified version of my code for testing purposes.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[something]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON; 

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @something INT

        DECLARE ROW_RES CURSOR FOR
            SELECT something 
            FROM something

        OPEN ROW_RES

        FETCH NEXT FROM ROW_RES INTO @something

        WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0) 
        BEGIN
            IF (@something > 0)
            BEGIN
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                     @profile_name = 'myprofile',
                     @from_address = 'do_not_reply@me.com',
                     @recipients = 'me@me.com',
                     @copy_recipients = 'ccme@me.com',
                     @subject = @email_subject,
                     @body = @email_body,
                     @body_format = 'html'
            END

            FETCH NEXT FROM ROW_RES INTO @something
        END

        IF (@something = false )
        BEGIN
            UPDATE something 
            SET something = (@something) 
            WHERE something = @something
        END
        ELSE IF (@something = true)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO something (something) 
            VALUES (@something)
        END

        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @MESSAGE NVARCHAR(2000), @SEVERITY INT, @STATE INT
        --See if there is a hanging transaction
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
        --Rethrow the error to the calling application      
        SET @MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE() 
        SET @SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY() 
        SET @STATE = ERROR_STATE()
        RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, @SEVERITY, @STATE)      
    END CATCH

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
CLOSE ROW_RES
DEALLOCATE ROW_RES
```

Comment: Are you sure it sends emails when the transaction is rolled back or are you just assuming? [When executing sp_send_dbmail from within an existing transaction, Database Mail relies on the user to either commit or roll back any changes. It does not start an inner transaction.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql)

Comment: Yes, it sends all the emails. I assume that the roll back is just for database querying, but I'm a newbie though. But yes, the emails are getting sent.

Comment: AFAIK it puts the mails to be sent on a service broker queue so that should support transactions.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Do you know of any good articles or references that I can take a look at for making the messages get to the service broker queue first? As of now, I just have them right on the loop and that's why they all get sent out.

Comment: TBH I think you must be rolling back then starting a new transaction or something we can't see in the code you posted. This post shows that the email is not sent when the tran rolls back https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/135233/ddl-rollback-trigger-not-sending-email.html

Comment: I don't even see a `BEGIN TRAN` in your code. So probably all the statements are just running as individual auto commit transactions. Not all in the same transaction as you wanted.

Comment: YES! You were right. I took your suggestion and added "BEGIN TRAN" right after my "BEGIN TRY" and all the emails are queued, but not sent out. I tried it several times, commented and uncommented and all worked as expected. Thanks Martin. This solved my issue. I apologize for the newbie question. I'm barely touching these type of programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing a `BEGIN TRAN` to start a transaction. So your statements are all running in individual auto commit transactions rather than one combined transaction.

If you add `BEGIN TRAN` to the beginning of the try block then your existing code should work as desired.

Comment: YES! You were right. I took your suggestion and added "BEGIN TRAN" right after my "BEGIN TRY" and all the emails are queued, but not sent out. I tried it several times, commented and uncommented and all worked as expected. Thanks Martin. This solved my issue. I apologize for the newbie question. I'm barely touching these type of programs

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling `sp_send_dbmail` inside the cursor, you could instead insert all the meta data needed into a queue table, and after the cursor is complete, if there were no problems, you could run another cursor or loop that just sends the emails for each row in the queue table.

Comment: Yeah; I was afraid I would have to resort to something like that. So this would mean that I would have 2 loops to maintain right?

Comment: Yes, since you still need to call the sp_send_dbmail once per row in the queue.